# How can i get the metadata of a spring data JPA entity as json?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to get the metadata of a Spring Data JPA entity as JSON for sending REST response to front end application.

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA with REST.

**Role.java**

```
package com.myapp;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role implements Serializable {

@Id
private int id;

private String name;

public Role() {}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name= name;
}
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.myapp;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
private int id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_role")
private Role role;

private Boolean status;

public User() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name= name;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public Boolean getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}
```

I want the output for **User.java** as follows

```
{
  "id": "int/integer",
  "name": "String",
  "role": { "id": "int/integer", "name": "String" },
  "status": "Boolean"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: plz have a look at: https://www.foreach.be/blog/comparing-java-rest-documentation-frameworks ..and maybe also at: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-rest-docs-versus-springfox-swagger-for-api ..you'd have to decide for one of the tools & install/configure accordingly.